# Searching for a vector inside another vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to search thorough a vector to see if an element appears. Once this element appears along with others, i want to re-search through the original to see if this second element appears else where within the vector. The end result should show the first element being found and then the information of where the second element appears.

```cpp
void searchband()
{

    ifstream artist("newartist.txt");
    string SBand;
    cout << "Please enter the band you want to seach" << endl;
    cin >> SBand;
    system("CLS");
    while (artist >> forname >> surname >> bandnum)
    {

        band.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < bandnum; i++)
        {
            string tmp;
            artist >> tmp;
            band.push_back(tmp);
        }
        artist >> role;
        if (find(band.begin(), band.end(), SBand) != band.end())
        {


            cout << forname << " " << surname << endl;
            cout << "Played for: ";
            ostream_iterator<string> output_iterator(cout, " ");
            copy(band.begin(), band.end(), output_iterator);
            cout << " " << endl;
            cout << " " << endl;
            newband = band;

        }
            if (find(band.begin(), band.end(), newband) != band.end())
            {


                cout << forname << " " << surname << endl;
                cout << "Played for: ";
                ostream_iterator<string> output_iterator(cout, " ");
                copy(band.begin(), band.end(), output_iterator);
                cout << " " << endl;
                cout << " " << endl;

            }
            system("pause");
            cin.get();
            main();

    }
}
```

This gets the error code

> error C2678: binary `'=='` : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type `std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>` (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I think it may be because

```
vector<string> = newband
```

but that is the only way i can think of to pass the vector information over is to another vector

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "find a vector of variables"? Please show an example input and a corresponding desired outpiut.

Comment: i dont really understand what you want to do. Is it [`std::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) you are looking for? Can you provide an example input and output?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please try an clarify with a more rigorous explanation and with some concrete examples.

Comment: A different approach would be to sort the vectors and then compare. You can also remove duplicates from a vector and optionally collect the duplicates in another vector. I can post some examples if you are interested.

Comment: Are you the same person that posted [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55710467/2610810) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55575623/2610810) questions? The code is basically identical.

Comment: @Caleth No, but we are working together on this problem. The second of those questions has been answered but the first one is the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) does what you are looking for:

> Searches the range [first, last) for any of the elements in the range [s_first, s_last).

Example (also taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of)):

> ```
> #include <algorithm>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <vector>
>
> int main()
> {
>     std::vector<int> v{0, 2, 3, 25, 5};
>     std::vector<int> t{3, 19, 10, 2};
>
>     auto result = std::find_first_of(v.begin(), v.end(), t.begin(), t.end());
>
>     if (result == v.end()) {
>         std::cout << "no elements of v were equal to 3, 19, 10 or 2\n";
>     } else {
>         std::cout << "found a match at "
>                   << std::distance(v.begin(), result) << "\n";
>     }
>  }
> ```

Comment: @SeanHeaney the last part of the example prints where the match was found. Note that `find_first_of` only returns the first occurence. It does not find all of them, though you can utilize `find_first_of` to do exactly that. From your question it is still not perfectly clear what you want to find. The edit say you merely want to see if **any** of the elements appear in the first vector. While the first paragraph talks about finding **all** of the elements. If you need more help, please include input and expected output in the qeustion

Comment: @SeanHeaney please include an example of input and output. for example: input vector: "Rome Paris NewYork" search vector: "Rome Paris", expected output: "Rome Paris", is this what you want?

Comment: expected input "Rome" Expected output:"Visited By Ryan who also visited Paris, Prauge" Expected input "paris , prauge output:visited by Henry an ryan , Visited by henry and jenny

Comment: @SeanHeaney sorry, this is not sufficient information. Where are the names coming from? Ryan who? Imagine you talk to someone who has not the slightest idea about the problem you are currently trying to solve, you can only communicate in written form. How would you explain what you need? ;)

Comment: @SeanHeaney in different words, the only meaningful way I could come up with to get "Visited By Ryan who also visited Paris, Prauge" when the only input is "Rome" would be `std::cout << "Visited By Ryan who also visited Paris, Prauge";`

Comment: Pretty much i have a vector of strings for each person. I am searching for a specific thing. The code will output all people who contain that particular string inside their vector. It will be output as a vector containing strings. These people will have other strings in their vectors. I want to re-search using a different search and it'll will given a new list of people based on that new place i've searched. I want to be able to keep both sets of information so that you can trace form the first search, who's been there, then look and where that person's been and look who has also been there.

Comment: @SeanHeaney what you describe is your code. Code is much better at describing code rather than text. I can only speak for myself, but I am completely lost already after the one third of you comment. Please read about [mcve]. Try to concentrate on only one part of the code: searching the vector and think of that as a function taking some input and producing some output. I still dont understand what the input/output to/from that function would be

Comment: Edited the question hope this makes more sense

Comment: @SeanHeaney this seems like a completely different question now. Fine in this case, because there is only my answer, and I dont really care about it getting useless. Normally when in the course of clarification it turns out the your question is different you better open a new one in case there are already answers. Anyhow just leave it like that, I will maybe come back later and fix the answer, if not someone else answers in the meantime

Comment: Was simply trying to describe the problem using holiday destinations as i thought it would make it clearer to understand. The problem at hand is still the same. Still trying to search for a vector within another vector. I added the error code as thought it would be helpful because there obviously wasn't enough detail originally. Any immediate help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: @SeanHeaney erm... only now I realized that the code is about bands not places to visit.... really no offense, but note that it does not help if you make things up, if you can show the real thing then do it instead of adding an extra layer of confusion by talking about something that is not the code you are looking at. Nevermind, it is just that I have to turn to other things for a while

Comment: Sorry for the added confusion, was trying to make it clearer to understand but obviously didn't. If you have any spare time to help it would greatly appreciated

Comment: @user4630355818 For your answer is there a way to find all rather tham just fimd first of?